php mail attachment encoded
I'm facing a problem with the attachments in my php mail system.
I get all the data correctly but the attachments it's in encoded format.
my html:
<form action="lavora-con-noi-process-form.php" method="POST" id="lavora-con-noi" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        
        <input type="file" id="pdf-upload" name="pdf_file" accept=".pdf" style="border: none;" required>
          
    </form>

and the php part:
<?php
$showThankYou = false;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // Retrieve form data
  $recipient_email = "myemail@email.com"; 
  $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nome"]); 
  $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Validate email format
  $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["messaggio"]);


  // Check if PDF file was uploaded
  if (isset($_FILES['pdf_file']) && $_FILES['pdf_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['pdf_file']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['pdf_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['pdf_file']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['pdf_file']['size'];

    // Validate file type
    if ($file_type != "application/pdf") {
      echo "Errore: solo file PDF sono consentiti.";
      exit;
    }

    // Read the uploaded file content
    $file_content = file_get_contents($file_tmp);

    // Create a boundary string for the multipart email
    $boundary = md5(uniqid());

    // Prepare the email headers
    $headers = "From: myemail@email.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$boundary."\"\r\n";

    // Create the email body
    $mail_body = "--PHP-mixed-" . $boundary . " \r\n";
    $mail_body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n";
    $mail_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $mail_body .= "Nome: $name\nEmail: $email\nMessaggio:\n$message";

    // Attach the PDF file
    $mail_body .= "--PHP-mixed-" . $boundary . " \r\n";
    $mail_body .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
    $mail_body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
    $mail_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
    $mail_body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content)) . "\r\n";

    $mail_body .= "--$boundary--\r\n"; // Closing boundary for the email


    // Send the email
    if (mail($recipient_email, "Nuovo messaggio da $name", $mail_body, $headers)) {
      $showThankYou = true;
    } else {
      // Get the error message
      $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
      echo "Ci sono stati problemi con l'invio dell'email: $errorMessage";
    }
  } else {
    echo "Errore durante il caricamento del file";
  }
}
?>

<?php if ($showThankYou): ?>
  <p>Grazie per averci inviato un messaggio! Ti contatteremo in tempi brevi per rispondere alle tue domande.</p>
<?php endif; ?>

and this is what I get in my email:
I've been trying to change my php different times. Could it be something on the sever that causes the problem?


You don't have any \r\n after the $message in the body. You also sometimes use \n instead of \r\n. Writing your own email code is difficult. Most people use something like PHPMailer or a third-party service. The latter also solves any problems with getting emails delivered.

This might be related to place where you view this pdf. Different mail apps show it differently. Try to respond to that email and see if respond contains valid PDF. In the end you might include it as inline attachement.

Agreed, not sure why you'd give yourself the headache of trying to build this kind of delicate email syntax by hand when libraries like PHPMailer have solved this already, and are free, and have other advantages too.

@KIKOSoftware yeah. it seems the way to go. I'll definitely use PHPMailer. Thank you so much.
